# how can I search letter pairs matches with regex?

Tags: python, regex, match

I'm using regex to find occurrences in a string python, for example: "cw cx", "cw cx av", "cw cx dr wt" or "cw cx qw hv eb". The match can be 2, 3, 4 or 5 pairs. I'm thinking something like this "([a-zA-Z]{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{2})" Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{2}(?: [a-zA-Z]{2}){1,4}\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cE3bT5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Try this: `([a-zA-Z]{2} ){1,4}[a-zA-Z]{2}`